# TinyMCE AutoResize plugin, reset overflow

Tags: plugins, callback, tinymce, overflow, autoresize

the autoresizer sets overflow-y:hidden on the editor to do its height calculations but never resets it back to overflow-y:auto. Where/How in my tinyMCE init can I specify a callback after the autoresizer is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset it after the Tinymce is initialized using the parameter

```
   setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {

            // reset it back here !

        });
   },
```